# Asterisk characters inside <kbd> tags are not rendered correctly

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

When using the following markup:

```
<kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>
```

It renders as:

You can see a live example of this causing a problem in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334895/3728901

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a bug. In Markdown, an asterisk is used to indicate that the subsequent text should be rendered as italic (one asterisk) or bold (two asterisks)—see [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold) of the editing help.

If you want to render a literal asterisk, you need to escape it with a backlash character.

This renders fine:

```
<kbd>\*</kbd> <kbd>\*</kbd>
```

<kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>